# Hello guys i was wondering why in BigQuery the select from has multiple dots is that how the table name appears in there? for example

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

`bigquery-public-data`.samples.shakespeare

**just from below example;**

-- Which names appear as words in Shakespeare's plays?
SELECT
name AS shakespeare_name
FROM top_names
WHERE name IN (
SELECT word
FROM `bigquery-public-data`.samples.shakespeare
);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigQuery tables are stored in datasets and datasets are set up within projects.

The dots separate project id, dataset name and table name. In your example, "bigquery-public-data" is the project id, "samples" is the dataset and "shakespeare" is the name of the table.

You can validate this visually when you look at the explorer and where the "shakespeare" table is located:

[image: project]

[image: dataset and table]

Comment: Thank you this well appreciated @ErrHuman